# Replace data within MySQL with PHP if NULL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm working on a small personal project while learning the basics of PHP and MYSQL. The project downloads an XML feed and inserts the data within MYSQL and every minute the data is refreshed and updated (working fine)  The problem I'm having is updating the column 'actualstart' that needs to be updated just once from NULL to the DATETIME for each row when the below criteria is met. I've tried various if combinations and WHERE parameters but no joy

```
if ($Time1 > $start  && $Time1 < $halftimestart) {
        $sqlstart = "REPLACE livescores (Id,actualstart) VALUES ('$Id','$actualstart') "; 
        mysqli_query($con,$sqlstart);
```

Full code below

```
    <?php
//mysql
$con = mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//xml
    echo "updated";
    $livegoal = simplexml_load_file('livescores.xml');
    foreach ($livegoal as $livegoalinfo):
        $Id=$livegoalinfo->Id;
        $League=$livegoalinfo->League;
        $Round=$livegoalinfo->Round;
        $Date=$livegoalinfo->Date;
        $HomeTeam=$livegoalinfo->HomeTeam;
        $HomeGoals=$livegoalinfo->HomeGoals;
        $HomeTeam_Id=$livegoalinfo->HomeTeam_Id;
        $AwayGoals=$livegoalinfo->AwayGoals;
        $AwayTeam=$livegoalinfo->AwayTeam;
        $AwayTeam_Id=$livegoalinfo->AwayTeam_Id;
        $Time=$livegoalinfo->Time;
        $Time1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $Time);
        $Location=$livegoalinfo->Location;
        $Stadium=$livegoalinfo->Stadium;
        $HasBeenRescheduled=$livegoalinfo->HasBeenRescheduled;
        $HomeGoalDetails=$livegoalinfo->HomeGoalDetails;
        $HomeGoalDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeGoalDetails);
        $AwayGoalDetails=$livegoalinfo->AwayGoalDetails;
        $AwayGoalDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayGoalDetails);
        $HomeLineupGoalkeeper=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupGoalkeeper;
        $HomeLineupGoalkeeper1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupGoalkeeper);
        $AwayLineupGoalkeeper=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupGoalkeeper;
        $AwayLineupGoalkeeper1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupGoalkeeper);
        $HomeLineupDefense=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupDefense;
        $HomeLineupDefense1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupDefense);
        $AwayLineupDefense=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupDefense;
        $AwayLineupDefense1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupDefense);
        $HomeLineupMidfield=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupMidfield;
        $HomeLineupMidfield1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupMidfield);
        $AwayLineupMidfield=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupMidfield;
        $AwayLineupMidfield1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupMidfield);
        $HomeLineupForward=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupForward;
        $HomeLineupForward1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupForward);
        $AwayLineupForward=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupForward;
        $AwayLineupForward1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupForward);
        $HomeLineupSubstitutes=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupSubstitutes;
        $HomeLineupSubstitutes1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupSubstitutes);
        $AwayLineupSubstitutes=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupSubstitutes;
        $AwayLineupSubstitutes1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupSubstitutes);
        $HomeLineupCoach=$livegoalinfo->HomeLineupCoach;
        $HomeLineupCoach1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeLineupCoach);
        $AwayLineupCoach=$livegoalinfo->AwayLineupCoach;
        $AwayLineupCoach1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayLineupCoach);
        $HomeSubDetails=$livegoalinfo->HomeSubDetails;
        $HomeSubDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeSubDetails);
        $AwaySubDetails=$livegoalinfo->AwaySubDetails;
        $AwaySubDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwaySubDetails);
        $HomeTeamFormation=$livegoalinfo->HomeTeamFormation;
        $AwayTeamFormation=$livegoalinfo->AwayTeamFormation;
        $HomeTeamYellowCardDetails=$livegoalinfo->HomeTeamYellowCardDetails;
        $HomeTeamYellowCardDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeTeamYellowCardDetails);
        $AwayTeamYellowCardDetails=$livegoalinfo->AwayTeamYellowCardDetails;
        $AwayTeamYellowCardDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayTeamYellowCardDetails);
        $HomeTeamRedCardDetails=$livegoalinfo->HomeTeamRedCardDetails;
        $HomeTeamRedCardDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $HomeTeamRedCardDetails);
        $AwayTeamRedCardDetails=$livegoalinfo->AwayTeamRedCardDetails;
        $AwayTeamRedCardDetails1 = str_replace(array("'"), '', $AwayTeamRedCardDetails);
        $actualstart=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $actualhalftime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $actualsecondhalftime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$start = 0;
$halftime = "Halftime";
$halftimestart = 45;

// Create connection

$sql = "INSERT INTO livescores (Id, League, Round, Date, HomeTeam, HomeGoals, HomeTeam_Id, AwayGoals, AwayTeam, AwayTeam_Id, Time, Location, Stadium, HasBeenRescheduled, HomeGoalDetails, AwayGoalDetails, HomeLineupGoalkeeper, AwayLineupGoalkeeper, HomeLineupDefense, AwayLineupDefense, HomeLineupMidfield, AwayLineupMidfield, HomeLineupForward, AwayLineupForward, HomeLineupSubstitutes, AwayLineupSubstitutes, HomeLineupCoach, AwayLineupCoach, HomeSubDetails, AwaySubDetails, HomeTeamFormation, AwayTeamFormation, HomeTeamYellowCardDetails, AwayTeamYellowCardDetails, HomeTeamRedCardDetails, AwayTeamRedCardDetails  ) VALUES ('$Id', '$League', '$Round', '$Date', '$HomeTeam', '$HomeGoals', '$HomeTeam_Id', '$AwayGoals',  '$AwayTeam', '$AwayTeam_Id', '$Time1', '$Location', '$Stadium', '$HasBeenRescheduled', '$HomeGoalDetails1', '$AwayGoalDetails1', '$HomeLineupGoalkeeper1', '$AwayLineupGoalkeeper1', '$HomeLineupDefense1', '$AwayLineupDefense1', '$HomeLineupMidfield1', '$AwayLineupMidfield1', '$HomeLineupForward1', '$AwayLineupForward1', '$HomeLineupSubstitutes1', '$AwayLineupSubstitutes1', '$HomeLineupCoach1', '$AwayLineupCoach1', '$HomeSubDetails1', '$AwaySubDetails1', '$HomeTeamFormation', '$AwayTeamFormation', '$HomeTeamYellowCardDetails1', '$AwayTeamYellowCardDetails1', '$HomeTeamRedCardDetails1', '$AwayTeamRedCardDetails1')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE League='$League',Round='$Round',Date='$Date',HomeTeam='$HomeTeam',HomeGoals='$HomeGoals',HomeTeam_Id='$HomeTeam_Id',AwayGoals='$AwayGoals',AwayTeam='$AwayTeam',AwayTeam_Id='$AwayTeam_Id',Time='$Time1',Location='$Location',Stadium='$Stadium',HasBeenRescheduled='$HasBeenRescheduled',HomeGoalDetails='$HomeGoalDetails1',AwayGoalDetails='$AwayGoalDetails1',HomeLineupGoalkeeper='$HomeLineupGoalkeeper1',AwayLineupGoalkeeper='$AwayLineupGoalkeeper1',HomeLineupDefense='$HomeLineupDefense1',AwayLineupDefense='$AwayLineupDefense1',HomeLineupMidfield='$HomeLineupMidfield1',AwayLineupMidfield='$AwayLineupMidfield1',HomeLineupForward='$HomeLineupForward1',AwayLineupForward='$AwayLineupForward1',HomeLineupSubstitutes='$HomeLineupSubstitutes1',AwayLineupSubstitutes='$AwayLineupSubstitutes1',HomeLineupCoach='$HomeLineupCoach1',AwayLineupCoach='$AwayLineupCoach1',HomeSubDetails='$HomeSubDetails1',AwaySubDetails='$AwaySubDetails1',HomeTeamFormation='$HomeTeamFormation',AwayTeamFormation='$AwayTeamFormation',HomeTeamYellowCardDetails='$HomeTeamYellowCardDetails1',AwayTeamYellowCardDetails='$AwayTeamYellowCardDetails1',HomeTeamRedCardDetails='$HomeTeamRedCardDetails1',AwayTeamRedCardDetails='$AwayTeamRedCardDetails1' ";


        if ($Time1 > $start  && $Time1 < $halftimestart) {
        $sqlstart = "REPLACE livescores (Id,actualstart) VALUES ('$Id','$actualstart') "; 
        mysqli_query($con,$sqlstart);

}



mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    endforeach;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Obvious the code above is rough and will improve over time

Many Thanks

Comment: Holy variables! Now spot the typo.

Comment: What error are you getting and what result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: MySql has a command called [coalesce](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/coalesce/) that will return the first non-null argument in the list.

Comment: Well the if statement above works fine and adds a TIMEDATE stamp within the actualstart column but when the script runs again the date changes...  so im trying to add a NULL condition to only update 'acutalstart' if its NULL. Hope that makes sense and sorry for any typos its nearly 2am here

Comment: Thank Austin Brunkhorst... edits done... MySQL :)

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It looks like you're in dire need of an ORM. Have you considered using something like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IFNULL`:

```
$sqlstart = "UPDATE livescores 
            SET actualstart = IFNULL(actualstart, '$actualstart') 
            WHERE id = '$Id'";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I've  previously tried the IF NULL option but not with the WHERE criteria.. will test and update soon

Comment: If you don't use `WHERE`, it updates all the rows, not just the row with the ID you want.

Comment: Hello... I've done various tests and the above works great